# Connect mangoDB Atlas with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I can't connect to MongoDB database, yet I tried everything ! I have successfully replaced the password.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://vibess:0KksWIBp6slcBLm0@cluster0.iuvoi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("Connected !!"))
  .catch(() => console.log("Not connected!"));
```

Here is the Database

[MangoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjbR5.png)

Comment: i think you have posted sensitive info. better remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need another function to complete the operation. the function is usually called **run** then you need to write all the operations of your server in the scope of this function. here is an example of a server of mine **Also you need to declare the name of your database before text retrywrites=true**

```js
//connect to mongodb
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.qtoag.mongodb.net/Teletale?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect((err) => {
      const db = client.db("Teletale");
      const djiPackages = db.collection("Devices");
      const bookingsCollection = db.collection("bookings");
      const testimonialCollection = db.collection("testimonials");
      const usersCollection = db.collection("users");

      // ==============GET API ====================
      //GET API
      app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send("Welcome to Teletale");
      });

      //GET API (dji Package)
      app.get("/Devices", async (req, res) => {
        const result = await djiPackages.find({}).toArray();
        res.send(result);
      });

      //GET API (users)
      app.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
        const result = await usersCollection.find({}).toArray();
        res.send(result);
      });

      // verify admin data form database
      app.get("/users/:email", async (req, res) => {
        const email = req.params.email;
        const query = { email: email };
        const user = await usersCollection.findOne(query);
        let isAdmin = false;
        if (user?.role === "admin") {
          isAdmin = true;
        }
        // localhost:5000/users/admin@admin.com will show true
        res.json({ admin: isAdmin });
      });

      //GET API (Bookings)
      app.get("/bookings", async (req, res) => {
        let query = {};
        const email = req.query.email;
        if (email) {
          query = { email: email };
        }
        const result = await bookingsCollection.find(query).toArray();
        res.send(result);
      });

      //GET Dynamic (Bookings)
      app.get("/bookings/:id", async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const result = await bookingsCollection.findOne(query);
        res.send(result);
      });

      //GET Dynamic (products)
      app.get("/Devices/:id", async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const result = await djiPackages.findOne(query);
        res.send(result);
      });

      //GET (testimonials)
      app.get("/testimonials", async (req, res) => {
        const result = await testimonialCollection.find({}).toArray();
        res.send(result);
      });

      // ==========================POST API=========================
      //POST API (dji Package)
      app.post("/Devices", async (req, res) => {
        const newTours = req.body;
        const result = await djiPackages.insertOne(newTours);
        res.send(result);
      });

      //POST API (users)
      app.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
        const user = req.body;
        const result = await usersCollection.insertOne(user);
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
      });

      //POST API (Bookings )
      app.post("/bookings", async (req, res) => {
        const newBooking = req.body;
        const result = await bookingsCollection.insertOne(newBooking);
        res.send(result);
      });

      //POST API (Testimonials )
      app.post("/testimonials", async (req, res) => {
        const newBooking = req.body;
        // console.log(newBooking);
        const result = await testimonialCollection.insertOne(newBooking);
        res.send(result);
      });

      // ======================DELETE API ========================
      //DELETE API(Bookings)
      app.delete("/bookings/:id", async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const result = await bookingsCollection.deleteOne(query);
        res.send(result);
      });

      //DELETE API(drone)
      app.delete("/Devices/:id", async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const result = await djiPackages.deleteOne(query);
        res.send(result);
      });

      // =================Update API====================
      app.put("/bookings/:id", async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const newStatus = req.body;
        const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const options = { upsert: true };
        const updateDoc = {
          $set: {
            data: newStatus.newData,
          },
        };
        const result = await bookingsCollection.updateOne(
          query,
          updateDoc,
          options
        );
        res.send(result);
      });

      //upsert Google user data
      app.put("/users", async (req, res) => {
        const user = req.body;
        const filter = { email: user.email };
        const options = { upsert: true };
        const updateDoc = { $set: user };
        const result = await usersCollection.updateOne(
          filter,
          updateDoc,
          options
        );
        res.json(result);
      });

      // add admin role
      app.put("/users/admin", async (req, res) => {
        const user = req.body;
        const filter = { email: user.email };
        const updateDoc = { $set: { role: "admin" } };
        const result = await usersCollection.updateOne(filter, updateDoc);
        res.json(result);
      });
    });
  } finally {
    // await client.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the app crashes

Comment: Don't directly use my codes. My codes is  just for showing you what you need to write. 
const db = client.db("Teletale");  here in the field inside the parenthesis you will put the name of your database and in the next line you will put the collection of your data etc . the code here has many functionality. ignore all of them just try to understand the top section.

Comment: The above is correct, also remember to check if version of mongoose is compatible with mongodb version.
Also check ATLAS security settings, sometimes it has ip whitelisting and may just refuse connections if you come from a different ip.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I also removed "useCreateIndex: true,"